# Using Syntaxnet POS tags in python?

Tags: python, nlp, text-parsing, pos-tagger, syntaxnet

I want to use the parser tags (ex: VBD ROOT, NN nsubj, etc.) of syntaxnet in python to help create a chatterbot. The input is done in the console.

Question: How can I get in a variable the result of only VBP ROOT and nothing else? I was able to print the ASCII version of the parse tree with this call: `subprocess.call(["echo 'Bob brought the pizza to Alice.' | syntaxnet/demo.sh"], shell =True)` but I am a bit confuse on how to get to a particular variable and store it in a python variable.

p.s: I started to learn python a week ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're a Python beginner and all you want to use is the part-of-speech (POS) tags, SyntaxNet is probably overkill. [SpaCy](https://spacy.io/) is easy to use and quite accurate.

Answer (score 3):

I am also a beginner both in python and SyntaxNet. What I did was that I changed the output of SyntaxNet from tree to a tab delimited text file by deleting

```
  bazel-bin/syntaxnet/conll2tree \
  --task_context=$MODEL_DIR/context.pbtxt \
  --alsologtostderr
```

from [demo.sh](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/demo.sh) in SyntaxNet folder. Run this command echo `'open Book, which I have written with laboratory writer, with libreoffice writer.' | syntaxnet/demo.sh > output.txt`

The text file is like this:

[image]

Then you can read data with `csv.reader`, turn it to `list` and then search column 4 of `sublists`(column numbers starts from '0') and column 7 for finding `ROOT`

I put the code of the above explanation:

```
#read from Syntaxnet output tab delimited textfile
def readata(filename):
      file=open(filename,'r')
      lines=file.readlines()
      lines=lines[:-1]
      data=csv.reader(lines,delimiter='\t')
#make a list of lists
      lol=list(data)
      return  lol
#find the verb which is ROOT of the sentence
      lists=readata(filename)
      for sublist in lists:
            if sublist[7]=='ROOT' and sublist[4]=='VBP': 
                  word=sublist[1]
```

Note that this code is written by a bignner but it atleast worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple post on my blog showing how to load syntaxnet output into into NLTK's structures, to get noun-phrases, based on PoS and dependencies into a DependencyGraph:

http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2017/03/25/syntaxnet/